# Microsoft Project cannot access to Team Foundation Server

Tags: version-control, team-foundation-server, microsoft-office-2010

I'm trying to connect my Microsoft Project 2010 to a team foundation server in order to create a project connected to my server in order to edit tasks and so on...

Well, in the ribbon top bar, I click the `Team` Tab and then the `Choose Team Project` button...

It makes me choose the tfs instance and the project collection but when I submit my request clicking on `Ok` this error message appears:

> TF82019: The mapping file contains
>   unrecognized XML.

And the procedure is aborted.
Can anybody tell me what to do?
In Internet there is not much about this...

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say where you might be failing as there are a few setps that need to happen to get this all to work. I've only done it once. I used the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412647.aspx

Did you do all the command line stuff to map fields in PS to to fields in TFS? It sounds like something has gone afoul in the mappings?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412647.aspx#FieldMapping

Good luck!